# Is there any alternatives to registerColumnType on upgrade from Hibernate-core:5.6.10.Final to 6.1.5.Final

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am currently upgrading from Spring-boot-starter-parent 2.7.3 to 3.0.0. The hibernate-core dependency for this is 6.1.5.Final.

This has broken my custom SQL dialect I had implemented.

The server dialect class is below:

```
public class ServerDialect extends SQLServer2012Dialect {

    public ServerDialect() {
        super();
        registerColumnType(Types.NVARCHAR, "nvarchar(max)");
        registerHibernateType(Types.NVARCHAR, StandardBasicTypes.STRING.getName());
    }
}
```

Since upgrade, these method's can no longer be resolved.

All I have changed is:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.3</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

to

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

I have looked up the documentation and searched for alternatives with no success.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It might be worth evaluating if this Dialect is required for your project post upgrade - prior to Hibernate 6 it was common to provide the `Dialect` version via the `hibernate.dialect` setting, but it is no longer the recommended strategy. More information on this can be found in the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#portability-dialectresolver).

If this is not a suitable resolution, there is however a workaround for your issue.

[SQLServer2012Dialect](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/SQLServer2012Dialect.html) is now deprecated so as part of this migration should should consider refactoring your custom dialect to use the recommended [SQLServerDialect](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/SQLServerDialect.html).

You should be able to make use of [resolveSqlTypeDescriptor](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/AbstractTransactSQLDialect.html#resolveSqlTypeDescriptor(java.lang.String,int,int,int,org.hibernate.type.descriptor.jdbc.spi.JdbcTypeRegistry)) to achieve the same or similar functionality - for example;

```
@Override
public JdbcType resolveSqlTypeDescriptor(String columnTypeName,
                                         int jdbcTypeCode,
                                         int precision,
                                         int scale,
                                         JdbcTypeRegistry jdbcTypeRegistry) {

    switch (jdbcTypeCode) {
        case Types. NVARCHAR, Types.CHAR -> jdbcTypeCode = StandardBasicTypes.STRING.getSqlTypeCode();
        // ETC
    }

    return super.resolveSqlTypeDescriptor(
            columnTypeName,
            jdbcTypeCode,
            precision,
            scale,
            jdbcTypeRegistry
    );
}
```

However, given your example above - this should not be required as the newer Hibernate should automatically perform an `NVARCHAR` mapping like this for you.

Comment: This has solved my issue! I simply removed the dialect.

Comment: Thank you for the hint regarding to overriding the `resolveSqlTypeDescriptor` method in a custom dialect. This helped me solving an issue of the `OracleDialect` (wrong type mapping based on column precision) which led to `java.sql.SQLException: Numeric Overflow` when using native queries / dynamic sql.