# registerColumnType has been removed in hibernate orm 6

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to migrate from Hibernate 5 to 6 and I am a bit stuck with following code:

```
public class MySQL8DialectBitFixed  extends MySQL8Dialect  {
    public MySQL8DialectBitFixed () {
        // This class is being added b/c hibernate/MySQL doesn't work with boolean fields in the db.
        // The data is not persisted properly.
        super();
        registerColumnType(Types.BIT, "tinyint(1)");
    }

}
```

It seems that the registerColumnType has been removed in hibernate 6 and their replacement is not trivial. Is there a way to replace registerColumnType?

Comment: you can find a relevant answer on this [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74645194/is-there-any-alternatives-to-registercolumntype-on-upgrade-from-hibernate-core5)